# NoSQL alternative of sqlite in Python

Tags: python, database, nosql

I love Python's sqlite: it is simple, it just needs one additional file to work and no additional dependencies. It is also supported by fancy ORMs, like peewee. But are there any nosql databases which can be used from python without any additional programs installed? I'm fine with additional python package, but I definitely don't want to, for example, get additional container for Mongo. What are my options?

UPD: I've done some research, and looks like my only option is [litedb](http://github.com/JonathanVusich/litedb). Code looks great, but there are no docs at all, so I guess it isn't usable right now

Comment: Thanks @keddad for asking this quesetion! So hard to find any info on this on the internet. All we know how SO is a bit of a geek hell, but luckily this question wasn't closed too early and could get some answers, also from you, thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah, btw. Sqlite with JSON column is a potential solution, too:  https://www.beekeeperstudio.io/blog/sqlite-json

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After all, I found [tinydb](http://github.com/msiemens/tinydb). Seems great to me.

Answer (score 3):

[LowDB](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb) is a good alternative and also can be used with [Python Implementation](https://pypi.org/project/lowDB/).

Also there are more alternatives which are file-based NoSQL databases like [Flata](https://github.com/harryho/flata) and [TinyDB](https://tinydb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **liteDB**

All the neccesary documentation can be found here [documentation](https://www.litedb.org/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30626445)